# Solving Oth order Bessel function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, bessel-functions

I need to solve the following equation:

$$ \frac{d^2 \theta}{dr^2} + \frac{1}{r} \, \frac{d\theta}{dr} - \frac{2h}{kt} \, \theta = 0$$

I think its a zeroth order Bessel function but I'm not sure how to proceed with the solution. 
Thanks in advance for any help.